# enable and disable menu items of mdiparent from loginform in c#

Tags: c#, mdiparent

i have two form,**home and login**.On home there is menu called **file** and menu items like **login,logout** 
when i run the application login form will open and after login home page will open.menuitems on home form will **enabled=true** when login is successfully
i click on logout menu this will **enabled=false** all menu other than login.When i click on login menu login form will open,after successfull login my home form menu should be **enabled=true**

So my problem is that i am not been able to **enabled=true** menu from my login form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you are showing LoginForm as ShowDialog(), not MDI Child. And if your Login is successful you can set the dialog result to OK or Yes. And in the next statment you can enable / disable the menu items

```
mnuLogin_Click()
{
FrmLogin frmLogin = new FrmLogin();
if(frmLogin.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
//Enable menu here.
}
}
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: thank you sir for replay ,i am trying enabled = true but nothing is happening ,can you give me some suggestion to do it

Comment: You are setting the dialog result as OK right? Then it should work. Did you tried putting break point?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it from your login form but from the main form. Also don't do it immediately after login but each time the menu is about to be opened, set each item enabled property.